# I missed 1 digit from my passport number when booking an appointment for a Germany Schengen visa. Will the visa officer handle it?

Tags: passports, schengen-visas, applications

I missed 1 digit from my passport number while I booking an appointment for a Germany Schengen visa [short term]. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Note that the number of digits on your passport is fixed (at least for a given country) and probably contains some check digits or something like that. That means, the first time your wrong number is entered into a computer it will (should at least) immediately notice that this is not a valid passport number.

Answer (score 7):

> Will this be a problem?

IMHO, yes. The passport number is a critical element of your application.

When my partner applied for a Schengen transit visa for Germany a few months ago, the appointment confirmation stated that *the data provided in the application cannot be amended or corrected subsequent to making the appointment. In the case of error(s) in the data provided, the appointment at the embassy must be cancelled and a new request made with the correct data.*

Check your appointment confirmation to see if it contains the same warning. If it doesn’t, you could try emailing the embassy/consulate for advice.